# Dropdown list selectedindex is not calling when we reset that DropDown to "select" and then after that select previously what we selected

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, .net

I have a dropdown box which is filled by dataset at code behind and I have setted that Property as `AutoPostback = true`..

based on selected value I am again filling another dropdown box.

It is working well but when I reset to first Dropdown box to 0th index("Select") and again I can select the same dropdown value. In this case it is not calling PostBack.

Sample code:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlHeaderField" runat="server" Width="160px" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlHeaderField_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="True">
</asp:DropDownList>
<asp:ImageButton runat="server" ID="btnAdd" ImageUrl="~/Images/add_btn.png" CssClass="ImageButton" OnClientClick="btnAdd_Click();return false;" />
```

JavaScript:

```
function btnAdd_Click() { 
    var ddlDocType =document.getElementById(ClientID + "ddlDocumentType");
    var ddlHeader = document.getElementById(ClientID + "ddlHeaderField");
    var ddlOperator = document.getElementById(ClientID + "ddlOperator");
    AddRow(tbl, ddlDocType, ddlHeader, ddlOperator); 
}
function AddRow(tbl, ddlDocType, ddlHeader, ddlOperator) {
    //Here I am creating table and then reset to default values(like Select in Dropdown)
    ddlHeader.selectedIndex = 0;
    ddlOperator.selectedIndex = 0;
}
```

Now first I am selected index as 2 and its get postback and added a row, after that I am reset those values and now again if I select index 2 then the postback is not working.
Other than that index then I will postback.

Answer (score 0):

This is because javascript is client side. You are changing the selected index back to your defaults only on the client side as you're doing it in you're function. Therefore, when you change the value again to 2, the 'OnSelectedIndexIndexChanged' method won't be fired, as the server doesn't believe it has been changed.

One option would be to change the values back to their defaults in the OnSelectedIndexChanged event in the code behind.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved my problem.

I just add __doPostBack event in javaScript to call the SelectedIndexItemChanged then it is working fine....

```
__doPostBack("ctl00_TopPlace_ddlHeaderField", "ddlHeaderFieldchange");
```

Thanks